# Parsing date string

Tags: java, android

I am trying to parse a formatted date back to a Date object but I keep encountering exceptions, here is my code:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy ", Locale.ENGLISH);
date = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
```

When I try a date like `Apr 17, 2016` it gives me an `ParserException` to say `Unparseable date: "Apr 17, 2016" (at offset 12)`

Comment: can u try with just 3 Ms. `SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy ", Locale.ENGLISH)`

Comment: "MMMM" means "full month name" which would mean "April" rather than "Apr". You want "MMM" meaning "abbreviated month name". *Always* check your format against the documentation when you run against problems like this. Also note that you have a trailing space in your pattern, which you appear not to have in your actual text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you provide a date format string, all of the characters must account for all of the text in the `dateString` somehow, including the literal space characters.

You have a space character at the end of your format string:

```
"MMMM d, yyyy "
```

Eliminate that space (or include a space at the end of your `dateString` string).

[The format strings `MMMM` or `MMM` will parse `Apr` just fine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

> **Text:** For formatting, if the number of pattern letters is 4 or more, the full form is used; otherwise a short or abbreviated form is used if available. For parsing, both forms are accepted, independent of the number of pattern letters.

Answer (score 2):

You have a little bundler in your date mask: The **last blank** is too many:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy ", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

It should be:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

That's why the error points to "offset 12": The DateFormat expects a blank at that position.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the last blank space on the string format.

You actually have

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy ", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

And it should be

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
```

Comment: Add `Date` before date

Comment: the space was the cause of my misfortune.